# Screen "Messed Up" during installation of Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 on Nvidia computer

Tags: 20.04, usb-installation

I don't know what else to call this except "Messed Up" (see image)
[image]
Here is what I did to install Ubuntu

1. Selected Install Ubuntu, the screen went crazy like in the picture
2. Selected Try Ubuntu and it worked! but then when I clicked Install
   ubuntu it went crazy
3. Selected Install Ubuntu (Safe Mode) and I could install (although I couldn't see the bottom of the screen so I had to hit tab and guess where NEXT was

I managed to install Ubuntu but then after rebooting, I see that screenshot

Here is what I have tried to do to isolate other causes

1. I tried 2 different USB drives
2. I tried different versions (18.04 desktop, 20.04 desktop)
3. I tried 2 different computers
4. I tried different monitors
5. I tried "jiggling" the HDMI cables
6. I even tried installing from Unetbootin instead of USB

The only conclusion I can draw is that it has something to do with the Nvidia graphics card.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can fix this?

Comment: when you boot from the usb and when you get the menu Install Ubuntu, Advanced Options etc... press e and add nomodeset before quiet splash https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/

Comment: Are you sure your installation media is valid and uncorrupted?  Did you do checksum/integrity checks of the ISO before writing it to USB?

Comment: @Nmath, yes I did a checksum check and it passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a while ago I had some problems with graphics since an old laptop I used couldn't go through ubuntu's splash screen without crashing.

To solve this, hold shift during boot, eventually you'll see the GRUB menu, you then want to press "e"

https://i2.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/edit-grub-menu.jpg

you then want to find the line where it says "Linux" at the start

https://i2.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/editing-grub-to-fix-nvidia-issue.jpg?resize=800%2C343&ssl=1

go to the end of that line, and type

```
nomodeset
```

https://i0.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/editing-grub-to-fix-nvidia-issue-2.jpg?resize=800%2C320&ssl=1

then press F10 or CTRL + X to save and exit.

if this doesn't work for you I suggest loading ubuntu into the USB/CD again, also make sure your using the right partition scheme, depending on if your using Legacy/UEFI boot mode

sorry that I had to send image links I'm New and don't have enough rep to emb the links in

Comment: So it worked. Could you maybe explain why it worked? Also, I noticed that now it only supports single monitor output, not dual

Comment: @puk I don’t know why but I think it disables Some Wayland features